# Display meta information in the wall post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-apps, facebook-recommendations

My page has meta information 
og:title
og:category
og:price

Is it possible to display those information when one shares the like on his wall? how? from what I tried on the  and the actual url + img are shown in the post: 
John recommends Title on MyApp.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to include key/value pairs in a regular feed post - if you're posting Open Graph actions you can have some properties of the object displayed in the feed stories but this isn't possible when supplying the feed data yourself.

See the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) docs for more info